# Insert Outlets in AppDelegate or Custom Cocoa Class?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode7

I was an iOS programmer and recently switched over to making Cocoa apps for Mac. When creating a project in `Xcode`, it seems there are two options:

**(1)** Using the `MainMenu.xib` default, insert buttons and link to `AppDelegate`. I have tried creating an `NSView` class and linking to that with no success.

**(2)** Creating an `NSViewController` class and linking the view from `MainMenu.xib` and any buttons to that.

Which of these methods is better when creating larger applications, with multiple `views` and `windows`?

**Edit**: What would be the best way to start out if not connecting anything to `AppDelegate`? Create an `NSWindowController` class with an `xib` and connect its view to a `NSViewController` class?

I guess overall I am confused as to which class I start with and what elements (window, views, buttons) to connect to what class file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a window object in your MainMenu xib and create a reference to it in your AppDelegate class. You will be able access items in it. But this is good only for a little learning.

You should start with an NSWindowController. For a first try, don't make any view controllers yet. Use the xib file and build your first window in the subclass of NSWindowController.

In AppDelegate, create an instance of the new class and open it.

Once you have mastered that, you can define view controllers for parts (or all) of you window's view.

If you need sample code, let me know, but it's a good exercise to work it out.

Comment: After many hours of Googling and playing around I finally figured out how to attain what I needed. Every view is kept in a main xib file, all linked in one NSViewController class. Then each view is associated with NSView class from the right menu in IB. That keeps everything in one xib and one ViewController class and nothing in AppDelegate.